# MySQL Nested query formatting

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have a database with 3 tables, A `VOLUNTEER` table, a `TRAINING_EVENTS` table, and a `TRAINING_INSTRUCTOR` table.

The `VOLUNTEER` table contains in formation about a person marked by a auto incremented `Vol_ID`.

The `TRAINING_EVENTS` table contains dates and times for an event marked by a auto incremented `Event_ID`. It also assigns each event an `Hours_Credited` field, which indicated how many credit hours a volunteer receives for being an instructor for that particular event.

The `TRAINING_INSTRUCTOR` table contains the `Vol_ID` and `Event_id`. (Indicating which volunteer is the instructor for an event).

I would like to have a query that finds which particular event a volunteer was an instructor at and then add up the credited hours for those events

The following code is what I attempted to use, but results in an error.

```
SELECT SUM(Hours_Credited)
FROM TRAINING_EVENTS AS TE, TRAINING_INSTRUCTOR AS TI
WHERE TE.EVENT_ID = TI.EVENT_ID AND TI.EVENT_ID IN
    (SELECT TI.EVENT_ID
    FROM VOLUNTEER AS V, TRAINING_INSTRUCTOR AS TI
    WHERE V.VOL_ID = TI.VOL_ID AND V.VOL_ID = 3);
```

Comment: You used `TI` as alias twice: One in the outer, one in the inner query

Answer (score 0):

You are re-using the alias `TI` inside the `IN` query.

Try this with the `TI2` alias...

```
SELECT SUM(Hours_Credited)
FROM TRAINING_EVENTS AS TE, TRAINING_INSTRUCTOR AS TI
WHERE TE.EVENT_ID = TI.EVENT_ID AND TI.EVENT_ID IN
(SELECT TI2.EVENT_ID
FROM VOLUNTEER AS V, TRAINING_INSTRUCTOR AS TI2
WHERE V.VOL_ID = TI2.VOL_ID AND V.VOL_ID = 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited to remove redundant join to TI and to pull for all VOL_IDs.

```
SELECT TI.VOL_ID, SUM(TE.Hours_Credited) as HOURS_CREDITED
FROM TRAINING_EVENTS AS TE,
(SELECT TI.EVENT_ID, TI.VOL_ID
    FROM VOLUNTEER AS V, TRAINING_INSTRUCTOR AS TI
    WHERE V.VOL_ID = TI.VOL_ID) AS TI
WHERE TE.EVENT_ID = TI.EVENT_ID
GROUP BY TI.VOL_ID
ORDER BY TI.VOL_ID;
```

Comment: You could also use the proper `join` syntax for a good answer

Comment: Thank you. This was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `JOIN`:

```
SELECT v.NAME, SUM(Hours_Credited) as 'Hours_Credited'
FROM TRAINING_INSTRUCTOR TI
join TRAINING_EVENTS TE
on TI.Event_ID = TE.Event_ID
join VOLUNTEER V
on TI.VOL_ID = V.VOL_ID
group by V.VOL_ID
```

You can try it here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b9694a/4

Answer (score 0):

If you have the input VOL_ID and you want to output the sum of HOURS_CREDITED by a volunteer, this query will resolve:

```
SELECT SUM(TE.Hours_Credited)
 FROM 
TRAINING_EVENTS AS TE, TRAINING_INSTRUCTOR AS TI
 WHERE 
TE.EVENT_ID = TI.EVENT_ID AND TI.VOL_ID = 3;
```